# ActionSheet with one button issue with ios 8

Tags: ipad, ios8, uiactionsheet

In my application i found that actionsheet is not displaying properly, so i create fresh demo project with single view and one button on button action i have write code like

```
-(IBAction)testActionsheet:(id)sender{
    UIActionSheet *objAction=[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"ActionSheet issue",nil];
    [objAction showFromRect:CGRectMake(300, 500, 90, 9) inView:self.view
               animated:YES];
}
```

but is show some cut from top side... do any one have solution for this, with actionsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIActionSheet is deprecated in iOS 8. 
please check this link 
[UIActionSheet is deprecated in iOS 8](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS//documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/index.html)

you can use UIAlertController instead of actionsheet

[UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS//documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIAlertController)

Comment: UIAlertController have also same issue.

Comment: Dont know why someone downvoted. UIActionSheet is deprecated in iOS8 so the Q is inaccurate.

Comment: @BipinPatel I'm facing same issue with UIAlertController as well,
What i found is if the arrow is at top/bottom side then its working fine with both(UIAlertController and UIActionSheet) but working for none if its on left or right side.

Comment: @Waseem thanks, the UI issue was related to arrow direction any and without title and message in ios 8.

Comment: Being "deprecated" does not mean "does not work anymore", please note that! UIActionSheet works in iOS8.